# how to crop to letterbox in iOS

Tags: ios, image

In IOS How can I crop a rectangular image to square letterbox so that it maintains the original aspect ratio and the remaining spaces are filled with black.  E.g. the "pad" strategy that transloadit uses to crop/resize their images.

http://transloadit.com/docs/image-resize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who stumbles onto this question and many more like it without a clear answer, I have written a neat little category that accomplishes this at the model level by modifying the `UIImage` directly rather than just modifying the view. Simply use this method the returned image will be letterboxed to a square shape, regardless of which side is longer.

```
- (UIImage *) letterboxedImageIfNecessary
{
    CGFloat width = self.size.width;
    CGFloat height = self.size.height;

    // no letterboxing needed, already a square
    if(width == height)
    {
        return self;
    }

    // find the larger side
    CGFloat squareSize = MAX(width,height);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(squareSize, squareSize));

    // draw black background
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, squareSize, squareSize));

    // draw image in the middle
    [self drawInRect:CGRectMake((squareSize - width) / 2, (squareSize - height) / 2, width, height)];

    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for convenience - heres a swift rewrite of @Dima's answer:

```
import UIKit

extension UIImage
{
    func letterboxImage() -> UIImage
    { 
        let width = self.size.width
        let height = self.size.height

        // no letterboxing needed, already a square
        if(width == height)
        {
            return self
        }

        // find the larger side
        let squareSize = max(width, height)

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(squareSize, squareSize))

        // draw black background
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
        CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, squareSize, squareSize))

        // draw image in the middle
        self.drawInRect(CGRectMake((squareSize-width) / 2, (squareSize - height) / 2, width, height))

        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return newImage
    }
}
```

Comment: Updated this code for Swift 5, worked for me. Minor changes for deprecated methods.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `contentMode` of the UIImageView with `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit`. You can also find this option for UIImageView if you use storyboard.

The set the `backgroundColor` of UIImageView to black (or other color of your choice).